# File extension for 'application/ole' attachment

Tags: content-type, ole, file-type, mapi

Email messages in RTF format can have embedded in-line attachment. MAPI gives file name of inline attachment but without extension. How to know the extension?

MAPI gives content-description as 'Picture (Device Independent Bitmap)'. I can depend on this data to compute file extension as BMP. But this works for BMP but not for PDF, WORD, EXEL. I would like to know if there is a solution (like looking in to REGISTRY) that works for everything without me changing the code for every file type.

Mime headers generated by reading MAPI properties of attachment. You see that attachment is missing extension.

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=ATT87266
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
content-type: application/ole;name="Picture (Device Independent Bitmap)"
content-description: Picture (Device Independent Bitmap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Embedded OLE attachments are not files, they are IStorage COM storage. If you look at an OLE attachment with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable, double click on the attachment), you will see that there is no `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` binary property where the regular by-value attachments are stored; what you have instead is `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` object (`PT_OBJECT`) property. You can open it in OutlookSpy by right clicking and selecting IMAPIProp::OpenProperty, then selecting IStorage as the interface.

The OLE storage will contain several streams that contain flags used by Outlook, metafile used to render the object when viewing it, and the actual data used by whatever OLE server was used to create the OLE attachment. You can look at the storage CLSID to figure out the application used to create the attachment. Once you know that, you can extract the raw file data from the application-specific storage stream inside that `IStorage`.

Comment: Thanks for response. As you have described, I am extracting attachment stored inside IStorage object, but I did not know about CLSID part. I will add that code. Thank you, Ramesh